# Docker is running but cannot access local development server [Django]

Tags: django, windows, docker, yaml

I can't access the Django's welcome page from locahost.

I've tried many of the answers already and nothing seems to be working. I've done the following:

- Changed my port from `8000` to `9000` and `exposed` them. I've `CMD` from the Dockerfile.
- Exposed several ports on the `docker-compose.yml` file but nothing works.
- Run `docker build .` several times after making changes
- Changed `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to `'*'` and `['*']`

Would appreciate your help.

**Config:**

```
Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89e8a

OS: Windows 10 Home

Docker Toolbox
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN apk update && apk add libpq
RUN apk add --virtual .build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev postgresql-dev
RUN pip install psycopg2
RUN apk del .build-deps

RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY ./myapp/myapp

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: sh -c "python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000"
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=postgres
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASS=postgres
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG}
      - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}
    volumes:
      - ./myapp:/myapp
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running on windows 10 Home and/or using Docker Toolkit, open Kitematic and click on web preview. This was what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your dockerfile seems to have missing the `EXPOSE` command. Add this in the end to your **dockerfile**

```
EXPOSE 9000
```

Comment: I did that. Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure on your host that port `9000` is available.

Comment: I don't get this, could you give an example?